# Embedding Python in C - Segfault

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault

From reading another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942128/how-to-pass-an-array-from-c-to-an-embedded-python-script), I am trying to embbed some some Python code into C:

**main.c**

```
#include <Python.h>

int callModuleFunc(int array[], size_t size) {
    PyObject *mymodule = PyImport_ImportModule("py_function");
    PyObject *myfunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(mymodule, "printlist");
    PyObject *mylist = PyList_New(size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        PyList_SET_ITEM(mylist, i, PyInt_FromLong(array[i]));
    }
    PyObject *arglist = Py_BuildValue("(o)", mylist);
    PyObject *result = PyObject_CallObject(myfunc, arglist);
    int retval = (int)PyInt_AsLong(result);
    Py_DECREF(result);
    Py_DECREF(arglist);
    Py_DECREF(mylist);
    Py_DECREF(myfunc);
    Py_DECREF(mymodule);
    return retval;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
    callModuleFunc(a, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

**py_function.py**

```
'''py_function.py - Python source designed to '''
'''demonstrate the use of python embedding'''

def printlist(mylist):
    print mylist
```

Then I compiled with:

```
gcc main.c -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7
```

But then I ran the app, it gives me a segmentation fault error:

```
/a.out
[1]    18890 segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: You assign a whole bunch of pointers from the return values of function calls, but don't check any of them for validity before using them.  You may also be mixing up types - do you get any compilation warnings?  (Though in C even the lack of such does not imply there are no such  problems)  You might also consider running your program under a debugger, and then using the backtrace command or whatever your debugger calls it to examine the stack and see where the failure occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were several problems with your code:

1. `Py_Initialize()` was not called.
2. `PyImport_ImportModule()` failed to find your python file, since in embedded Python you start **without** an initial module, relative to which the search can work. The fix is to explicitly include the current directory in `sys.path`.
3. `"(O)"` in `Py_BuildValue()` should use a capital `'O'`.
4. The `printlist` function should return a value (since that is what the C-code expects).

This should work:

**main.c**

```
#include <Python.h>

void initPython()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *sysmodule = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject *syspath = PyObject_GetAttrString(sysmodule, "path");
    PyList_Append(syspath, PyString_FromString("."));
    Py_DECREF(syspath);
    Py_DECREF(sysmodule);
}

int callModuleFunc(int array[], size_t size) {
    PyObject *mymodule = PyImport_ImportModule("py_function");
    assert(mymodule != NULL);
    PyObject *myfunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(mymodule, "printlist");
    assert(myfunc != NULL);
    PyObject *mylist = PyList_New(size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        PyList_SET_ITEM(mylist, i, PyInt_FromLong(array[i]));
    }
    PyObject *arglist = Py_BuildValue("(O)", mylist);
    assert(arglist != NULL);
    PyObject *result = PyObject_CallObject(myfunc, arglist);
    assert(result != NULL);
    int retval = (int)PyInt_AsLong(result);
    Py_DECREF(result);
    Py_DECREF(arglist);
    Py_DECREF(mylist);
    Py_DECREF(myfunc);
    Py_DECREF(mymodule);
    return retval;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    initPython();

    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    callModuleFunc(a, 4);
    callModuleFunc(a+2, 5);

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

**py_function.py**

```
'''py_function.py - Python source designed to '''
'''demonstrate the use of python embedding'''

def printlist(mylist):
    print mylist
    return 0
```

Comment: Hello Leon, it works. Now, I tried to add numpy to in the python source, but it gives me: ` main.c:18: callModuleFunc: Assertion `mymodule != ((void *)0)' failed`. Do you know what I have to do with my C code when I import other libraries in Python?

Comment: Did you `import numpy` in `py_function.py`? Does it work without problem when you run `py_function.py` with python directly? If so, then the problem is likely to be fixed by correctly populating `sys.path`.

Comment: The python module works correctly outside my C program. What do you mean by "correctly populating sys.path"? I see the following example: https://github.com/Frogee/PythonCAPI_testing/blob/master/testEmbed.cpp and the he appears not putting anything else but the "sys" module as you put it in the example above.

Comment: My initial solution contained the same fault as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624529/python-c-api-doesnt-load-module . I fixed it as per the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8859538/6394138) to that question.

Comment: I put the new code you have edited (the new initPython function), but when I run the following: `def printlist(mylist):
    import numpy as np
    a = np.array(mylyst, dtype=np.float32)
    print a` it also fails: `a.out: main.c:25: callModuleFunc: Assertion result != ((void *)0)' failed.`

Comment: I think you misspelled `mylist` in `np.array(mylyst, dtype=np.float32)`. Please test your python code in regular python environment, before trying it in embedded python environment.